# How to close thread detach C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I launched thread as detach. 
How to close thread from main function?

```
void My()
{
   // actions  
}


void main()
{

    std::thread thr7(receive);
    thr7.detach();

    // close ?

}
```

Comment: counter question: Why did you detach it? Once detached, it is... well .. detached

Comment: And can you please elaborate on what you mean by "close"? Do you want to give a signal to the thread that it should exit?

Comment: You can't close it. You have to programmatically end its role (i.e., the function has to reach its end). Maybe with a `stopped` boolean (semaphore) or something similar.

Comment: It will close when its main function ends, if it is an infinite loop you should message it ( you will need to implement that)

Comment: You don't "close" threads. The thread is running until it finishes executing. The `std::thread` is a handle you can wait on, but detaching it frees it - so once the thread has ended and you `.detach()` or `.join()` the `std::thread` instance, there's nothing else you need to do - all the resources associated with a thread are freed.

Comment: Define 'close thread detach'. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to tell the thread to exit its infinite loop and exit?

Then a simple boolean [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) object is all that's needed.

You initialize it to some value (say `true`), and in the thread loop while it's that value. Once you want the thread to exit, you change the value (to `false`) and then next when the thread loop iterates it will notice that and break the loop and continue with cleanup and exit.

Comment: in thread:

void My()
{
    while (end_thr){
        // some code
    }
    else{
         std::atomic;
    }
}

Right?

Comment: ... and in `main()` `join()` the thread (after setting the atomic) to make sure it has ended before leaving `main()`.

Comment: I don't believe the standard is clear for this question. What if it uses resources that are destructed after main() ends? In the general case unless it can be ensured it really isn't dependent on anything, maybe. But the OP just has `//actions`.

Comment: See this example: http://ideone.com/IA3r0G. If you `detach()` there is typically no output because clang (and gcc) just terminate all threads. I don't believe the standard specifies that but I can't imagine how anyone thinks a program is correct if threads get terminated at an arbitrary point in their execution and if they run on what they think happened to shared objects.

Comment: @Persixty The problem with that example is that you exit the process which indeed will kill all threads in that process, even detached ones. But if you exit the main *thread* then the process will live on until all threads have exited. However the OPs question isn't really about that but just how to signal a thread to exit. What happens after that we don't know and should not speculate in. It's indeed good to remind the OP about the possible dangers, but instead of telling me please tell the OP by adding comments to the question.

Comment: My example is exactly what the OP has put forward and my point is that yes, signaling will help but using detach OP will still have no idea which `actions` were completed before dropping out of `main()`. Should avoid `detach()` and use `join()` or providing a `stop` flag irrelevant because no guarantee any `while(!stop)` will ever be reached after `thr,detach();stop=true;return 0;` but is guaranteed after `stop=true;thr.join();return 0;`.

Answer (score 3):

### Short Answer:

Use a **shared variable** to signal threads when to stop.

### Long answer:

You cannot call `join` or `terminate` a thread directly from its parent once  `detach` is called unless you use some other methods.

Take a look at the following code (over simple and not very meaninful) which should show a simple way of doing what you are asking:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool finished = false;

void threadFunc()
{
    while(!finished)
    {
        
        std:: cout << "Thread doing work \n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
    }
    
    std::cout << "End of Thread \n";
}

int main()
{

    {
        std::thread t1(threadFunc);
        t1.detach(); // Call `detach` to prevent blocking this thread

    } // Need to call `join` or `detach` before `thread` goes out of scope

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
        std::cout << "Main doing stuff: \n";
    }
    std::cout << "Terminating the thread\n";

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);  
    finished = true;
    cv.notify_all();
    std::cout << "End of Main\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You use a shared variable to tell the threads when to terminate its execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the thread something like this:

```
std::atomic_bool running = false; // set to stop thread
std::atomic_bool closed = false; // set by thread to indicate it ended

void detached_thread_function()
{
    running = true;

    // acquire resources

    while(running)
    {
        std::cout << "running" << '\n';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    // release resources

    // set after all resources released
    closed = true;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread(detached_thread_function).detach();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    std::cout << "stopping detached thread" << '\n';

    running = false; // stop thread

    while(!closed) // you could code a timeout here 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    // or use a condition variable?

    std::cout << "end program" << '\n';
}
```

The thread is signaled to end its function and the thread sets a flag to let the main function know it is safe to exit.

If you have multiple threads you can use an atomic counter to exit when it reaches zero.